# How to update firewall to pass NFS traffic?

Tags: 10.04, firewall, nfs

I have set up the NFS Service using [these instructions](https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/Setting_Up_A_NFS_Service) and it was working fine last week but today I get this error:

> Root-NFS: Unable to get nfsd port number from server, using default

I restarted the NFS server like this:

> sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-­kernel­-server restart

and tried repeatedly but still get the error. When I google the error I see the suggestion

> update firewall to pass NFS traffic

How do I update firewall to pass NFS traffic? Or should it be some other issue since it was working fine last week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. After lunch the NFS server miraculously started working. Or maybe she is just not an early riser.